# Matching on types which implement a trait and therefore return it

Tags: pattern-matching, rust, traits

I'm trying out some specific builder pattern. Please don't mind the design here -- it's a tryout.

I have a `Renderer` type which yields a method `set_shape`. The argument type given to the call should implement the empty trait `IsRenderable`.
The login of the method then should differ between the struct types `Rectangle` and `Circle` which both implement the `IsRenderable` trait. Do not bother about the returning type.

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Rectangle {
    pub origin: Point,
    pub height: usize,
    pub width: usize,
}

trait IsRenderable {}

impl IsRenderBuilder for Rectangle {}

impl<'a> Renderer<'a> {
    // logic that needs lifetime 'a
    pub fn set_shape<T: IsRenderable>(shape: T) -> Box<IsRenderBuilder> {
        match shape {
            _ => panic!("WTF!"),
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to do something like this.
**PSEUDO**:

```
match shape {
    Rectangle => return RectangleShapeBuilder,
    Circle => return CircleShapeBuilder,
    _ => panic!("WTF!"),
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `match`, you should add a method on your `IsRenderable` trait that returns the appropriate builder for the particular implementor.

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Rectangle;

pub trait IsRenderable {
    fn new_builder(&self) -> Box<IsRenderBuilder>;
}

impl IsRenderable for Rectangle {
    fn new_builder(&self) -> Box<IsRenderBuilder> {
        Box::new(RectangleShapeBuilder)
    }
}

struct RectangleShapeBuilder;

pub trait IsRenderBuilder {}

impl IsRenderBuilder for RectangleShapeBuilder {}

pub fn set_shape<T: IsRenderable>(shape: T) -> Box<IsRenderBuilder> {
    shape.new_builder()
}
```

You might even use an associated type to avoid boxing the `IsRenderBuilder`:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Rectangle;

pub trait IsRenderable {
    type Builder: IsRenderBuilder;

    fn new_builder(&self) -> Self::Builder;
}

impl IsRenderable for Rectangle {
    type Builder = RectangleShapeBuilder;

    fn new_builder(&self) -> Self::Builder {
        RectangleShapeBuilder
    }
}

pub struct RectangleShapeBuilder;

pub trait IsRenderBuilder {}

impl IsRenderBuilder for RectangleShapeBuilder {}

pub fn set_shape<T: IsRenderable>(shape: T) -> T::Builder {
    shape.new_builder()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the associated Type!

Comment: Also: I think the return type of `set_shape` in the second code snippet should be `<T as IsRenderable>::Builder` to avoid possible name conflicts?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: I don't think name conflicts are a problem, since `T::Builder` is statically resolved to mean "the associated type `Builder` in trait `IsRenderable`", as all the compiler knows about `T` is that it implements `IsRenderable`. Rust doesn't work like C++ templates, where dependent types are only resolved at template instantiation time. Adding another trait bound might cause an ambiguity, but then it can be addressed when the ambiguity is raised, rather than going straight to the heavyweight syntax.

Comment: @FrancisGagné Ah yes, thanks for the clarification! :)